# Get selected value from asp SharePoint DropDownList of custom class type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, drop-down-menu

I am writing a SharePoint app. There I have page with drop down list. I have 
a handler for SelectedIndexChanged. I want to get the selected value but as `CustomObject` and the only option I see is `string`. I tried `SelectedValue` and it is still `string`.

That's how I set the list:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<CustomObject> customList = //retrieving data
    myDropDownList.DataSource = customList.Select(x => new { x.Name, Value = x});
    myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
    myDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
    myDropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

And that's one of the ways I tried:

```cs
protected void myDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var index = groupingDropDownList.SelectedIndex;
    CustomObject obj =  (CustomObject)myDropDownList.Items[index].Value;
    obj.DoSomething();
}
```

Is it even possible? Or do I have to have somewhere Dictionary with with objects?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to leverage the html5 data attributes that you can then place onto the dropdown options. Here is an example of what you could do with your data.

```
          // add Agencies' addresses as HTML5 data-attributes.
            var agencies = agencyNames.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < requesting_agency.Items.Count - 1; i++) {
                requesting_agency.Items[i + 1].Attributes.Add("data-address", 
                agencies[i].address);
                servicing_agency.Items[i + 1].Attributes.Add("data-address", 
                agencies[i].address);
            }
```

Then when processing the information you could do something like so.

```
    var index = groupingDropDownList.SelectedIndex;
    var selectedText = myDropDownList.Items[index].SelectedValue;
    var selectedValue = myDropDownList.Items[index].Attributes["attribute"];
    // put into obj
    // do something with object
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but It is not what I meant - attribute value can only be a string. And Item has no property `SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

You 're binding a object `(x => new { x.Name, Value = x})` to dropdown value, you should bind actual value to it.

Test demo:

```
public class CustomObject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public CustomObject(int _ID,string _Name)
        {
            this.ID = _ID;
            this.Name = _Name;
        }
    }
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<CustomObject> customList = new List<CustomObject>();
            customList.Add(new CustomObject(1,"test1"));
            customList.Add(new CustomObject(2,"test2"));
            myDropDownList.DataSource = customList.Select(x => new { x.Name, Value = x.ID });
            myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
            myDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
            myDropDownList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer but it is what I wrote about - it still is string (or int converted to string) and that is not what I want.